# Does continuity of measures hold for uncountable unions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As the title suggests, I wonder whether continuity of measures holds for uncountable operations? I.e., is it true that $E_\alpha \uparrow E \Rightarrow \lim_{\alpha}\mu(E_\alpha )= \mu (\cup_\alpha E_\alpha)$, $\alpha \in I$ for some uncountable index set $I$?

The only proofs I've seen for continuity of measure use countable additivity, and it's clear to me that uncountable additivity of measures does not make sense. However, is there a straight forward way to prove or disprove uncountable continuity?

Comment: **Any** uncountable set is the  union of its points...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general, no. Take $I=[0,1]$ (note the closedness at $1$!) and define
$E_\alpha = \{0\}$ if $\alpha<1$ and $E_1 = [0,1]$. You now have
$$\bigcup E_{\alpha} = [0,1]$$ you have $$E_\alpha \subseteq E_\beta$$ for $\alpha < \beta$, there's even a limit
$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 1} \mu(\alpha)$, but it equals $0$.

Comment: Thanks,that makes it perfectly clear.